# How do I change a UIButton background picture when an action in a UIAlertController is clicked?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uialertcontroller

```
@IBOutlet weak var myPictureOutlet: UIButton!

@IBAction func myPictureAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Chnage Pic", message: "to Change the pic, press the button below", preferredStyle: . alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "change picture", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.myPictureOutlet.setBackgroundImage(ButtonImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

My goal is to:

1. create an `UIAlertController` when a `UIButton` (with a default picture) is clicked
2. then, when a user clicks on the button in the `UIAlertController`, it changes the `UIButton` picture.

I am having a little trouble with this task. The `UIAlert` is working when I touch the `UIButton`, however the `UIButton` background is not changing. Please review my code and tell me if something is wrong.

Comment: Tell us what problem you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should actually work. You don't need this line though:

```
alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

UIAlertController will remove it for you after you press the alert button.

Also to improve your code just refer to the IBAction sender like this:

```
guard let button = sender as? UIButton else {
    print("Ooops, not a button!")
    return
}
button.setBackgroundImage(ButtonImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
```